# Encrypted and access-restricted iCloud Drive folders on iOS and iPadOS

Tags: ios, icloud, encryption, apfs, ipados

I use my iPad frequently in a teaching environment where it is unlocked and used by other people when presenting. Also, when I work with iPad in a shared office (I use iPad with Magic Keyboard as a laptop replacement), I sometimes forget to lock it when I get up for a few minutes (drinking, talking, etc.). It automatically locks after a few minutes, but — only after a few minutes.

Folders with sensitive content should therefore be additionally protected (both encrypted on a cloud storage as well as protected against accessing them when the iPad is unlocked: passkey or biometry). This would be similar to the newly introduced protected notes in Apple‘s Notes app, which Apple introduced, I guess, for the above mentioned use-cases.

So, is there any way to encrypt and access-restrict a folder on iPad that is shared using iCloud Drive, without using third-party software?

Comment: Do other people have access to the PIN code? If you're signed into your Apple ID, and leaving it 'open', then that's going to be lax. Sadly, iPads are not designed for multi-user environments, unless you use the Shared iPad feature, which requires device management software. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/deployment/dep9a34c2ba2/web

Comment: Other people do not have access to the PIN code but *all* folders in the Files app can be accessed without it. That is my problem. Regarding the Classroom app: Thank you, I did not know about this.

Comment: Isn‘t this basically asking how to encrypt a folder on iPadOS/iCloud without using third party solutions? If yes, the answer is simply „this is not possible right now“.

Comment: Encryption and access restriction. I was hoping for new ideas, e.g., different settings for creating a disk image (file format, partition map, …) or something else I have not thought about.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible (sub-optimal) solutions:**

- Until a few days ago, I used the third-party app Cryptomator. It has worked most of the time but recently I have had problems, so I deleted it from my devices.
- I‘m aware that there are other third-party tools like Cryptomator such as Boxcryptor or Tresorit. I am not writing an extensive list here since I‘m looking for a native solution with no third-party involvement for my most sensitive data.
- To find an alternative not involving third-party software, I used the Disk Utility app on my Mac to create encrypted APFS images, both  a sparsebundle and a DMG. But I cannot open those on iPad. Interestingly, when I format an USB stick with an encrypted APFS using the Disk Utility of my Mac, I can access the files on my iPad when I connect the USB stick to it.
- Using an encrypted ZIP file would be possible, but unzipping and zipping it every time I change its content is not what I want.
- Dropbox offers its Vault with an additional layer of protection for folders. But I don‘t like to use another third-party cloud storage provider.
- Apple recently introduced Advanced Data Protection for iCloud. It uses end-to-end encryption for various data including files and folders stored in iCloud Drive. However, the files are directly accessible when my iPad is unlocked. I also do not want to activate this for all my iCloud data but only for sensitive data. (I actually like it that Apple stores encryption keys for my non-sensitive data.)

Comment: In your Q, you state you don’t want 3rd party solutions, but  in this A, 3 out of 6 points are about 3rd party solutions.  What you’re asking for is currently not possible. It’s impossible to shoehorn a feature into a service that doesn’t offer it natively.